# Search only specific bookmarks folder in chrome without subfolders

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, javascript, bookmarks

How can I search a chrome bookmarks folder and not its subfolders?

Chromes default bookmarks manager is amazing along with its layout but it would be a whole lot better with this feature for organizing efficiently

Answer (score 0):

Bookmark Manager and Viewer.
Just right-click on the folder, and search.
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/bookmark-manager-and-view/mnhojcjhcilkgkmijhphlbmghmmdhlfg

Answer (score -1):

The best I've found is the Bookmarks Manager Plus extension (formerly Atomic Bookmarks).  You sort (using the middle of the five icons on the right) by hierarchy and page down to the results in whatever folder(s) you want.

I use it to move bookmarks from the primary folder to its subfolders.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer is marked for possible deletion.  You could improve it by posting more information about the extension, perhaps even a screenshot.

Comment: Did you see my update?  Please post it; I'd like to add more.  I wasn't logged on so I don't know how that's handled.